# Vanishing of rotation of timelike unit vector in numerical relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I'm a bit confused. I don't think it is that difficult, but still don't manage :-(

So the question is why the rotation of the timelike unit-vector in numerical relativity
$$n_\mu=-\alpha \nabla_\mu t$$
vanishes. $\alpha=\left(-g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu t\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is a normalization constant and $t$ the coordinate time.

The rotation then is $$\nabla_\mu n_\nu - \nabla_\nu n_\mu$$ as far as I expect, which becomes
$$-\alpha \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu t - (\nabla_\mu \alpha)(\nabla_\nu t) + \alpha \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu t + (\nabla_\nu \alpha)(\nabla_\mu t) = (\nabla_\nu \alpha)(\nabla_\mu t) - (\nabla_\mu \alpha)(\nabla_\nu t)$$
because $$\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu]}t=0 \, .$$ But I think $\alpha$ can depend on the coordinates so it doesn't seem clear why the entire expression should vanish, right?

**edit:** So to add further context this is basically a question from "Shapiro - Numerical Relativity" (p.27, Eq.2.23) or see also exercise 2.10 where it is to show that the twist $$\omega_{ab} = \gamma_a^c \gamma_b^d \nabla_{[c}n_{d]}$$ vanishes ($\gamma_a^b = \delta_a^b + n_a n^b$ is the projector onto the hypersurface). Shapiro also defines
$$ \omega_a = \alpha \nabla_a t = -n_a$$ and claims $$\omega_{[a}\nabla_b \omega_{c]}=0$$
so it doesn't really matter if I write $n$ or $\omega$. What matters is that either vector is normal to the $t=$const hypersurfaces. I also think the above bracketing must contain a typo, because $[abc]$ doesn't make sense. For the specific case of the SS-metric in isotropic coordinates we have
$$\alpha=\frac{1-M/2r}{1+M/2r}$$
so it does depend on the coordinates.

Comment: Why does [abc] not make sense? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242521/tensor-index-notation-with-e-g-square-brackets

Comment: Also why do you try to show that $\nabla_{[\mu} n_{\nu]}$ vanishes when the problem is to show that $\omega_{ab} = 0$. The contractions with the projector are absolutely going to be relevant for that calculation.

Comment: Thanks about pointing out the $3$-permutation. Haven't seen that before and the author only introduces the $2$-permutation in the beginning. I have actually thought about this maybe being a generalization, but then I thought that the author would have definitely introduced it, when he also introduced the already better known $2$-permutation. Adding to this, the author of the book in Exercise 2.10 ($\omega_{ab}=0$) refers to the problem $$\omega_{[a}\nabla_b \omega_{c]}=0$$ and so $$\nabla_{[\mu} n_{\nu]}=0$$ would have been a close alternative in case of misprint which also looks like a curl.

Comment: Though I have a question about your links where it says $$F_{[a}G_{bc]}=\frac{1}{3!}(F_a G_{bc}-F_a G_{cb}+F_b G_{ac}-F_b G_{ca}+F_c G_{ab}-F_c G_{ba}) \, . $$ Why is the third term $+F_b G_{ac}$, so positive? If the notation means anti-symmetrization, then any permutation introduces a minus sign when starting with $F_a G_{bc}$. But I need only 1 permutation so I would expect this term to be negative.

Comment: I think he just made a typo. It's really hard to type that correctly in Latex. Most GR books have an appendix with these rules in the back. Hopefully this information sets you on the right track for solving the problem.

Comment: Yes thanks! Solved it.

Comment: Awesome! I am going to post my hint about the three permutation as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$n_{[i} \nabla_j n_{k]} = n_i \nabla_j n_k + n_j \nabla_k n_i + n_k \nabla_i n_j - n_i \nabla_k n_j - n_j \nabla_i n_k - n_k \nabla_j n_i $$